# Is there a .NET encoding type that will return every byte in the underlying file as a character with the same ordinal value?

Tags: .net, character-encoding, binary

This is my question:

> Is there a .NET Encoding object/type that will decode every byte in a file to a character with the exact same ordinal value as the one in the file, basically do a 1-to-2 mapping between a byte in the file an the character ordinal value?

### More details

I'm reading text data, which contains some binary values, ie. an integer encoded as 4 bytes. The data has to be read through a TextReader-class because I'm getting it from an external programs standard output. The data I get back is sometimes mangled, due to encoding issues. Basically, the .NET streams are decoding the data from the external program and sometimes switches out a character so that whatever byte/character ordinal value the external program output is not the same as the one I read in .NET.

### Background information

I am communicating with an external program, Mercurial, over standard input/output, and for some reason they decided to output some data as binary.

The protocol looks like this:

```
<type:single-byte char><length:32-bit integer><data:string>
```

The type is a single-byte character that just tells me whether this is error output, standard output, or the result of executing the command.

The length is a 32-bit integer, output as 4 bytes on the stream.

The data is a string, consisting of a sequence of bytes of the aforementioned length, but these characters can be encoded with the default encoding of Mercurial.

For instance, if I ask Mercurial to use codepage 1252 (standard Windows) encoding, then the string will be encoded in that encoding.

However, and here's the problem: **the length will not be, of course**

If I configure the .NET Process object to use Windows-1252 as the encoding for the StandardOutput stream, like this:

```
psi.StandardOutputEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1252");
psi.StandardErrorEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1252");
```

Then at some point the decoding of data from the client gets out of sync, because one of the binary length values ended up being decoded and thus has a different ordinal value than the byte from the file.

My current example contained the euro-character at some point (as a printable character), however the byte from the file did not have the value 172 which was that of the printable character. Some decoding had taken place.

However, let's say I have a file containing every byte value possible.

Then I open the file up through a one of the TextReader descendants, and specify an encoding.

Is there any encoding that will let me use the [`TextReader.Read()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w3csw16.aspx) method and read every byte from that file, unchanged?

Basically, my decoding loop looks like this:

```
read one byte, convert to character
if character is 'r', 'e' or 'o':
    read next 4 bytes, assemble to integer
    read next X bytes (x=integer above)
    decode the bytes to a string using the encoding specified
```

However, I tried this and it tripped when the length contained the euro-character (as a printable character.) Apparently that character had one byte value in the file, but was decoded as another.

So to sum up:

> Is there a .NET Encoding object/type that will decode every byte in a file to a character with the exact same ordinal value as the one in the file, basically "no encoding"?

Comment: Can you read as a binary stream rather than as character/string data?

Comment: I don't know, can I? The reader object is retrieved from a Process object, the Process.StandardOutput reader.

Comment: Hum, seems there is a .BaseStream available here, I incorrectly passed the StandardOutput along as a TextReader, but they are actually StreamReader objects, I'll test the base-stream here.

Comment: I will self-answer this. I found the correct encoding to use, but I'm adding code to test if BaseStream is better to use here, no doubt it is.

Comment: "Windows-1252", that's kinda funny :)

Comment: @Hans What do you mean? Ah, if you mean that extra square there, that's because I'm on a iMac with Visual Studio up in a VMware Fusion session, and the keyboard on Mac's is a bit of a pain :P When I hit Ctrl+Home, as I'm used to in order to go to the top of the document, it just inserts that character, *and* then navigates.

Answer (score 4):

The correct encoding to use is "iso-8859-1", it decodes every byte to the same character ordinal. Apparently, it is also the *only* such encoding present in .NET (at least on my machine.) that has that capability/feature.

I wrote a [LINQPad](http://linqpad.net) test-program to figure this out:

```
void Main()
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[256];
    for (int index = 0; index < 256; index++)
        buffer[index] = (byte)index;

    foreach (var encodingInfo in Encoding.GetEncodings())
    {
        string s = encodingInfo.GetEncoding().GetString(buffer);
        var stream = new MemoryStream(buffer);
        var reader = new StreamReader(stream, encodingInfo.GetEncoding());
        bool equal = true;
        for (int index = 0; index < 256; index++)
            if (reader.Read() != index)
            {
                equal = false;
                break;
            }
        if (equal)
            Debug.WriteLine(encodingInfo.Name);
    }
}
```